# ¿Cómo selecciono texto depues de una etiqueta en Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

Tengo la siguiente estructura HTML:

```
<div>    \n <span> text1 </span>  text2   \n </div>
```

Y quiero seleccionar el text2:

```
reques.css("div::text").extract_first()
```

Pero esto me regresa el siguiente string:

```
"  \n"
```

¿Pueden ayudarme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si en lugar de `.extract_first()` usas `.extract()` obtienes una lista cuyos elementos son los textos que haya dentro del elemento seleccionado por el selector css que hayas usado. Para quedarte con el último puedes usar el índice `[-1]` en esa lista, lo cual es sintaxis estándar python.

Demostración:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
body = "<div>    \n <span> text1 </span>  text2   \n </div>"
reques = Selector(text=body)

textos = reques.css("div::text").extract()
print(repr(textos[-1]))
```

```
'  text2   \n '
```

Ten en cuenta que en tu caso, el selector `css("div::text")` toma los textos que están dentro del `div`, *pero no dentro de otros tags anidados* que éste pudiera contener, por lo que por este método no podrías extraer el texto "text1".

Si quisieras "convertir a texto plano", por así decir, todos los contenidos del `<div>`, es decir, obtener la cadena "text1 texto", yo usaría `.xpath()` para seleccionarlo, pues con `css` no tengo claro si sería posible. Sería así:

```
textos = reques.xpath("//div//text()").extract()
```

esto te deja en `textos` una lista con `['    \n ', ' text1 ', '  text2   \n ']`, que puedes juntar en una sola cadena con:

```
>>> "".join(textos).strip()
'text1   text2'
```